# WordPress: Redirect custom taxonomy archive to first post of the archive

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-taxonomy

I want to redirect every custom taxonomy to the first post in the loop.

For example:

I have a list of cities (taxomomy) like boston, denver, new york...
If I click the archive of the taxonomy, I want to redirect to the fist city in the list. In this case boston.

I found an example to do this here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/207298/redirecting-category-link-to-first-child-post

```
function redirect_cat_wpse_207298() {
  if (is_tax()) {
    global $post;
        wp_safe_redirect(get_permalink($post->ID));
    die;
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect','redirect_cat_wpse_207298');
```

But now it redirects always to the oldest post. Is there a way to change to order to the newest post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting redirected to the first published post of specific taxonomy.
you need to modify the query such that it must take the latest published post in your `$post` global variable.
Please try to add this filter and have a test. Hope this will resolve your query.

```
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'order_by_date_callback' );
 function order_by_date_callback ( $query ) 
 {
    if (($query->is_main_query()) && (is_tax()))
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
 }
```